# Group SQL Server Select Results into different Result tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible in SQL Server to "group" a result from a single query based on data in a specific column as if I ran multiple select queries?

I'm trying to find a lazy way out to extract data such as the below:

```
StoreId | ClientId   
  1     |    4     
  1     |    5      
  2     |    5     
  2     |    6      
  2     |    7   
  3     |    8
```

whereby every store ID result is grouped into its own table.

Whilst I can create a select statement for every store id to have it grouped, the list is too long to do so.

Comment: Prepare http://sqlfiddle.com with sample data

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do. What do you mean by group into tables? Do you want separate result sets for every store? Without more details there is little anybody can do.

Comment: Yes I need separate result sets for each store ID.

as mentioned I can just write select * from table where store ID =1, another select * from table where store id=2 etc etc and run all select queries at once so that I get multiple result sets. 

However the Store ID list is too long to create a select query for each.

Comment: I need to do this, so that I can extract each result set into its own separate excel worksheet

Comment: I guess I don't see why you don't `SELECT StoreId, ClientId FROM Table ORDER BY StoreId`.  Then, in your application, when the StoreId changes from the last row you know you need a new sheet.

Comment: I think what everyone is trying to tell you is, doing this in SQL is probably not the best approach.  Somethings you do in the DATA layer and other things you do in the Application Layer.  Other than the mention of Excel, you haven't mentioned what application would be extracting this data.  Are you tying an Excel sheet to a SQL Server database?

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine that this is really helpful but you can use dynamic sql to do something like this. I can't say I would recommend this approach for generating excel documents but whatever.

```
create table #Something
(
    StoreID int
    , ClientID int
)

insert #Something
select 1, 4 union all
select 1, 5 union all
select 2, 5 union all
select 2, 6 union all
select 2, 7

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''
select @sql = @sql + 'select StoreID, ClientID from #Something where StoreID = ' + CAST(StoreID as varchar(4)) + ';'
from #Something
group by StoreID

select @sql

exec sp_executesql @sql

drop table #Something
```